# SPRING BOOT :Spring Security circular bean dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm currently Implementing Token and Role Base Authentication Using Spring Boot   JWT  MySQL  following the tutoriel [https://github.com/team-learn-programming-yourself/jwt-youtube][1]
authentication with Spring Security for REST API using Spring Boot

it produces an error

```
    Description:
    
    The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
    
    ┌─────┐
    |  jwtRequestFilter (field private com.example.jwt.service.JwtService com.example.jwt.configuration.JwtRequestFilter.jwtService)
    ↑     ↓
    |  jwtService (field private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.example.jwt.service.JwtService.authenticationManager)
    ↑     ↓
    |  webSecurityConfiguration (field private com.example.jwt.configuration.JwtRequestFilter com.example.jwt.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.jwtRequestFilter)
    └─────┘

Action:
Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

the code for the dependencies producing error are as below :

**jwtRequestFilter**

```
package com.example.jwt.configuration;

import com.example.jwt.service.JwtService;
import com.example.jwt.util.JwtUtil;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("JWT token does not start with Bearer");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = jwtService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
package com.example.jwt.configuration;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/registerNewUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        ;

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**JwtService**

```
package com.example.jwt.service;

import com.example.jwt.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.jwt.entity.JwtRequest;
import com.example.jwt.entity.JwtResponse;
import com.example.jwt.entity.User;
import com.example.jwt.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class JwtService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtResponse createJwtToken(JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
        String userName = jwtRequest.getUserName();
        String userPassword = jwtRequest.getUserPassword();
        authenticate(userName, userPassword);

        UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(userName);
        String newGeneratedToken = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        User user = userDao.findById(userName).get();
        return new JwtResponse(user, newGeneratedToken);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findById(username).get();

        if (user != null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    user.getUserName(),
                    user.getUserPassword(),
                    getAuthority(user)
            );
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }

    private Set getAuthority(User user) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getRole().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRoleName()));
        });
        return authorities;
    }

    private void authenticate(String userName, String userPassword) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, userPassword));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement the authentication with JWT in a different class. Currently your `JwtService` is also a `UserDetailsService` which also does authentication. Which means the `UserDetailsService` now suddenly needs the `AuthenticationManager` which in turn needs the `UserDetailsService`. The configuration also needs this which in turn isn't possible due to that it needs the `Authenticationmanager`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove this from `WebSecurityConfiguration`:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
   ```

   The problem is that to be able to create the `jwtRequestFilter`, you first need a `JwtService`, which is created in `WebSecurityConfiguration`.

   `jwtRequestFilter` is injected into this configuration for no reason (it isn't used to create another `@Bean`). It will automatically be created by virtue of being a `@Component`. By using `@Autowire` in the above manner you have made WebSecurityConfiguration depend on the filter and thus created this circular dependency.
2. As per @M.Deinum's comment, your `JwtService` depends on `AuthenticationManager`, which in turns requires `JwtService` while it's being built, specifically here:

   ```
   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   }
   ```

   `JwtService` should only implement `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` - it should not be responsible for anything else.

   `createJwtToken(JwtRequest)` and `authenticate(String, String)` are the offenders here. You could just move them to another class, however, (and this could be 3.), depending on why and where and when you want to create such a token, responsibility for the authentication itself should remain with the AuthenticationManager, and token generation used for later password-less authorization could simply depend on a valid `User` argument, after that authentication has passed. There is no reason why `createJwtToken` should contain any call to `authenticate` at all. A refined approach is presented here (no affiliation): https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial

Comment: You're of course right, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security has had full JWT support since 2018, so my recommendation is the following.

Remove all the custom code since writing custom security is bad practice. Use the built in JWT functionality that comes with spring security.

First define that you want to use the oauth2resource filter but you want the filter to handle jwts instead of a traditional oauth2 token.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DirectlyConfiguredJwtDecoder extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }
}
```

add a custom decoder, that will decode the jwt using the built in `Nimbus` library that comes with Spring Security. Its easy to configure using the builder pattern [NimbusJWTDecoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api//org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/NimbusJwtDecoder.html)

Just add it as a `bean` and spring will automatically pick it up and inject it into the built in jwt filter.

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    // Use builder functions to configure how the JWT should be validated.
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.key).build();
}
```

If you wish to configure scopes and map these as roles in your application you can just add a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` that will take the scopes and map them to roles with the `ROLE_` prefix. If you don't add a converter your scopes will have the `SCOPE_` prefix.

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

Please read up on how JWTs in spring security work, there is an entire chapter on how to simple and easy implement the handling of JWTs in spring security.

[Spring security JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html)